# Feasible way to store temporary variables value in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In ASP.Net sometimes we need to temporary store variable's value.
So, I want to know that Is it feasible to store temporary value in ASP.Net control like Hidden field or to store it in Variables.

Comment: There are many many answers to this question. Can you give us an example of what the variable is and what it's for so we can suggest a suitable method?

Comment: Application or Session Variables does not do the trick for you?

Comment: When will you want to *retrieve* the value? Later in the same request? In a subsequent request?

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to live across requests, consider using session or cache.

Use sessions if the variable should only be available to one user.

```
Session["variable"] = "myValue";

string myValue = Session["variable"];
```

Or you could use cache if the variable should be available to multiple users.

Note:

Yes, you can temporarily hold a variable in a hidden field, but then it will be visible to the user. Do not expose things you don't want the user to see, or change.

Therefore you have the option to save the variable to a session/cache (instead of assigning it to a hidden field), and retrieve it on postback. The value will not be visible to the user.

Comment: Or an external file, or a query string parameter or a database. I don't believe you can answer this without knowing more about the nature of the variable...

Comment: He wants to know if it's feasible to store it in a hidden field. Then session and/or cache would be a suitable option.